# Cannot load json data on-click using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, json, angularjs

I am using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/) link to load json data on click. While reproducing the same in my VS2012, I added the following js and css files

```
<head>
 <link href="Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/myweb.js"></script>
</head>
```

where myweb.js and style.css are the javascript and css files from the link above. However, when I run the file, the data does not load. I am not able to click on the "here" part.

[image: Output after running the file]

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make it working?

Comment: Check console if you see any error.

Comment: You are loading both angular.js and angular.min and similarly both versions of jquery which is a bad practice.

Comment: @anpsmn no errors in the console.

Comment: @mohamedrias I was just being sure that I include everything. I have removed it from the code now.

Comment: What code are you using for the ajax part in your VS2012 version? Share that part

Comment: Because the /echo/json/ will work only in jsfiddle. you need to have appropriate services setup in the VS2012

Comment: @mohamedrias How can I set that up?

Comment: Put a JSON file (text file) that contains the same JSON string inside your application directory. Add a controller to output that file.

Comment: create a new .json file and put only the array [ ] you have mentioned in the mockDataForThisTest without any json stringily/encodeuri. Then replace the url in $http to json file url in your application server. It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid loading uncompressed and minified versions of angular , jquery and bootstrap.

It should be just:

```
<head>
 <link href="Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/myweb.js"></script>
</head>
```

Your jsfiddle works fine. So it's because of multiple versions of angular and jquery.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. I am not able to click on "here" part.

Comment: create a new .json file and put only the array [ ] you have mentioned in the mockDataForThisTest without any json stringily/encodeuri. Then replace the url in $http to json file url in your application server. It will work :)